# Asymmetrical search for special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to implement an asymmetrical search for a dictionary web app, so searching for *ü*, for example, will return only tokens that actually contain *ü*, but searching for *u* will return both *u* and *ü*. (This is so users who don't know how to type special characters can still search for them, but users who do know how to type them won't be inundated with the plain character forms unnecessarily.)

It has to all be client-side JavaScript without any external libraries.

I've managed to make the second search type work by running both the search term and the text I'm searching through the following function, effectively merging special characters with their plain counterparts:

```
function cleanUp(dirty) {
    cleaned = dirty.replace(/[áàâãäāă]/ig,"a");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/đ/ig,"d");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/[éèêẽëēĕ]/ig,"e");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/[íìîĩïīĭ]/ig,"i");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/ñ/ig,"n");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/[óòôõöōŏ]/ig,"o");
    cleaned = cleaned.replace(/[úùûũüūŭ]/ig,"u");
    return cleaned;
}
```

I then compare the strings to get my results with something like:

```
var search_term = cleanup(search_input.value);
var text_to_search = cleanup(main_text);
if (text_to_search.indexOf(search_term) > -1) ... //do something
```

It's not elegant, but it works. After cleaning up both strings the user can search for i.e. *uber* and get *über* even if they don't know how to type *ü*. But if they do know how, searching for *über* directly also returns things like *uber*, which is what I don't want.

I've already thought of things like checking for each special character separately for each search term or duplicating every dictionary entry that has a special character to produce a special-character and a plain-character version, but all of my ideas would seriously slow down the processing time for the search.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you declare the `cleaned` variable inside your function with the `var` keyword, if you want it to be private.

Comment: don't cleanup the input string, and if there's a special char in the input string, don't cleanup test_to_search either

Comment: How about instead of doing something with the cleaned copy of the dictionary, you use the dirty copy? I mean, still search in the cleaned dictionary, but only return strings from the dirty one. Since the dirty copy and the clean copy should still have the same size and will also have the 'same' characters in the same positions. This would mean that searching for _uber_ or _über_ will return _über_, and searching for _über_ can **only** return _über_

Comment: another approach could build a RegExp() from the input string, turning for example, "hum" into /\bh[úùûũüūŭu]m\b/g, and then calling text_to_search.match(myRX) instead of doing all those replacements and manipulating text_to_search each time...

Comment: if (myInput.match(dirty)) skipTheDictionayCleanup()

Answer (score 1):

The answer you posted sounds quite reasonable.

I would just like to suggest a cleaner way (pun intended) to code your `cleanup()` function and similar functions that do a series of string operations:

```
function cleanUp(dirty) {
    return dirty
        .replace(/[áàâãäāă]/ig,"a")
        .replace(/đ/ig,"d")
        .replace(/[éèêẽëēĕ]/ig,"e")
        .replace(/[íìîĩïīĭ]/ig,"i")
        .replace(/ñ/ig,"n")
        .replace(/[óòôõöōŏ]/ig,"o")
        .replace(/[úùûũüūŭ]/ig,"u");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking to see if the search term contained any special characters, and if it did, I didn't run it through `cleanup()`, and compared it to the original dictionary entry instead of the `cleaned` one. Thanks for the comments everyone.